# compileProgram returns two identical values in OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, pyqt, pyopengl

I am working on an app which is composed of two QtOpenGL widgets (both set in two different MainWindow). In my initializeGL() functions I write:

for the 1st GL widget:

```
vertexShader = shaders.compileShader(vertex, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
fragmentShader = shaders.compileShader(fragment1, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
program = shaders.compileProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader)
```

and for the 2nd one:

```
vertexShader = shaders.compileShader(vertex, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
fragmentShader = shaders.compileShader(fragment2, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
program = shaders.compileProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader)
```

But they both end up with the same "program" value, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the two QtOpenGL widget will have its own context. Since program ids are only unique inside their context, it is perfectly fine to get the same ids here.

Comment: Thus, if they both have the same value, how can I set the program I want outside my QOpenGL class? For example, I need to modify some uniforms outside my QOpenGl class.

Comment: You have to make sure that the correct context is bound when setting the values. The `QOpenGLContext` has a `makeCurrent(QSurface * surface)` method for this. Note, that a thread can only have one context current and each context can only be current in one thread.

Comment: That's what I've done and it works. By the way, I always use a single thread.